# How can I multiply all item in an array with laravel?

Tags: php, json, laravel, naivebayes, jsondecoder

i have array in controller with output like this

```
{
  "usia": 0.01761252446184,
  "wife_education": 0.078277886497065,
  "husband_education": 0.0058708414872798,
  "number_of_children": 0.17025440313112,
  "wife_religion": 0.86497064579256,
  "wife_now_working": 0.078277886497065,
  "husband_occupation": 0.23874755381605,
  "living_index": 0.078277886497065,
  "media_exposure": 0.048923679060665
 }
```

I would like to multiply each element of my array, example like this

> (usia * wife_education * husband_education * number_of_children *
>   wife_religion * wife_now_working * husband_occupation * living_index *
>   media_exposure)

Comment: Loop through the array and multiply each element.

Comment: can you give me the example  ?

Comment: I have answered it below

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: `array_product()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data in string and decode in JSON:

```
$data = '{  
    "usia": 0.01761252446184,  
    "wife_education": 0.078277886497065,  
    "husband_education": 0.0058708414872798,  
    "number_of_children": 0.17025440313112,  
    "wife_religion": 0.86497064579256,  
    "wife_now_working": 0.078277886497065,  
    "husband_occupation": 0.23874755381605,  
    "living_index": 0.078277886497065,  
    "media_exposure": 0.048923679060665  
}';


$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

Then loop through the `$data` for multiplication as:

```
$product = 1;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $product *= $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP foreach: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
$items = [];

foreach ($items as $item) {
    // do calculation here
}
```